Org-babel ignores RESULTS when generating beamer?
I'm using Org-babel to generate a bunch of pdfs from a single Org-mode file, compiling using Beamer.
Each subtree starts something like this:
* Introduction
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: pdf/slides001-intro.pdf
:END:
#+beamer: \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil


and then I export with org-beamer-all-subtrees-pdf
The problem is, if I have any code blocks, the RESULTS section is simply ignored in the generated tex and hence pdf. For example, if I have
        #+begin_src racket :results output code
        #lang plait 
        (+ 2 3)
        #+end_src

        #+RESULTS:
        #+begin_src racket
        5
        #+end_src


The RESULT bit with 5 never ends up in the resulting TeX. I checked and org-babel-export-evaluate is set to true.
Is there a way that I can tell org-babel to include the RESULT block in the generated output? Is there a variable to check if it's set wrong?

You need to say :results output both.

@NickD what does that do? I tried it but it didn't seem to change anything, but maybe something else is interfering

Sorry, I misremembered it: try adding :exports both to the source block header. See Exporting Code Blocks.

@NickD Perfect, that did it. It there any way to set that for all code blocks as the default?

See my answer below.

You can affect what is exported using the :exports header argument. It can take four values: code, results, both and none. So to export both the code and the results of evaluation, use a source block like this:
#+begin_src racket :results output code :exports both
...
#+end_src

See Exporting Code Blocks in the Org Mode manual.
To set a per-buffer header argument, use the following property:
#+PROPERTY: header-args:racket :exports both

That will append an :exports both header to each code block in the buffer that uses racket as its language.
You can affect all code blocks, regardless of language, as follows:
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports both

The colons can be confusing, so be careful. In the last example, the name of the property is header-args and its value is :exports both. In the previous example, the name of the property is header-args:racket and its value is :exports both.

EDIT: N.B. the names of the properties were wrong: they do not have an initial colon: header-args:racket and header-args resp. I was confused by the colons :-)
